# Dual boot windows with hibernation on bitlocked partitions

Tags: windows, windows-10, multi-boot, hibernate, dualboot

I have two installed Windows 10. One is for my work and one for personal usage. Both systems are secured by bit locker, so the one system does not have acces to the other one. I have administrator priviliges and bit locker key only for my personal use system.

Generally it works good, I can switch between systems easily, but just one important detail. I can't hibernate and go to other system. And this is very important to me to have that feature.

I have read that I can use other bootloader like GRUB2, which is not affected by hibernation, but the GRUB see Windows bootloader as one position, rather two separated Windows OSs. And when I go with it it asks for bit locker key. However, what is interesting my bios see that as 2 separated boot options:
[image: bios boot menu]

And I was able to run GRUB or run Windows Boot Manager. So perhaps I can do something to make it working as separated systems without bootmanager and use bios to pick one. I tried even to trick by copying this 100mb partition with bootloader - bios saw it as separate positions, but after hibernation it went to hibernated system anyway, without option to change...

Can you help me how to approach that issue?

Best Regards

Tomasz

EDIT: There is one physical disk (SSD M.2). I have Two main NTFS partitions (300 + 600GB), both encrypted with bitlocker with different keys. Apart from that I have two recovery partitions made by system installer,  one 100MB for Windows bootloader and one NTFS for GRUB2 (currently empty, because I have removed it).

Comment: are both oses on same disk ?? add details how disk are partitioned by editing your question

Comment: Yes, both on the same - updated info in the post.